# Zip multiple files to one folder

Tags: vb.net, zip

So I am having trouble trying to reconcile this concept as every change I do doesn't seem to fix the issue.

I have multiline `textbox` and can enter multiple values separated by commas and here are the details:

1. Each value represents a folder
2. And each folder has multiple documents/other folders inside
3. All of these values are in one main directory (lets call it folder path)

For example say I enter in my textbox ***"65635,65636"*** each of those represent a folder in the directory i.e. ***"\folderpath\65635"*** and ***"\folderpath\65636"***, I am trying to zip these whole folders via DotNetZiplib, I know how to do this if I specifically reference one folder but is there anywhere to loop through the textbox to get the names of the folders and have the files added to one zipped folder?

```
Using zip As New ZipFile = new ZipFile
 Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(folderpath & textboxvalue) 
 For each textboxvalue in directory.getfiles 
  zip.Addfile(textboxvalue)
```

The `zipfile` function I have would know to loop through these as opposed to assuming it's one big file.

Comment: @jean55 yes I checked zagglers as complete since it worked thank you! But I misunderstood my boss he said I can use 3rd party libraries and he wants to me loop through em all, I can do it if its single based on your answer  (my section of code in the question doesnt work, returns duplicates not sure why) and I dont know how, would you have any information on dotnetziplib? and is checking the answer meaning its correct? or do I have to do something else? sorry I am still getting the hang of commenting.

Comment: Please [**see this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) about accepting and voting for answers. This [**link**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is useful as well.

Comment: @Zaggler Thank you again for all the help and the links :) I am understanding more about vb with each question!

Comment: You are welcome, happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must split textbox values in array first to get numbers separated by comma. Next you will need Combine your folder with this splited text values, creating path correctly.

Check if folder exists in system if Yes then get all files from Directory and for each filename zip it.

Something like this:

```
Using zip As New ZipFile("your zip filename")
For Each str As String In textboxvalue.Split(",")
    Dim path as String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderpath, str)
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(path) = False Then
         Continue For
    End If

    Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(path) 

    For Each fileName As String In files
         zip.Addfile(fileName)
    Next 
Next
End Using
```

Comment: Could you please explain ***why the OP solution*** is not working. This post doesn't explain anything as to why the OP logic isn't working. Posting a solution is one thing, explaining the issue and how to fix the problem is a better solution that would help the OP understand the issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you, this is more beneficial.

Comment: @pho3nix thank you for replying! I tried this and the code executed fine without any errors but I dont see any zip file in the folderpath, I named my zip file "extract.zip" and there is no created zip file with that name, any Ideas about this? is there any way I can specify where the created zip goes? like a destination place?

Comment: You must create something like c:\projects\extract.zip and not just extract.zip (remember put Using ) or call zip.Close() before End Using